# Im stuck on a problem while trying to make a simple card game

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a simple python blackjack game for my second beginner project but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the 'dealer_sum = sum(dealer_cards)' line of code in the function to add cards to dealer

```py
def dealercards():
    global dealer_sum, player_sum
    if dealer_sum >= 17:
        if dealer_sum > player_sum and dealer_sum <22:
            print("You lost!")
        elif dealer_sum == player_sum:
            print("It is a tie!")
        else:
            print("You won!")
    else:
        dealer_cards.append(random.randint(1,11)
        dealer_sum = sum(dealer_cards)
        dealercards()
```

I tried changing the position of the functions and it didn't work.

```py
import random
dealer_cards = []
dealer_sum = 0
player_cards = []
player_sum = 0
status = " "
while len(dealer_cards) != 2:
    dealer_cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
    if len(dealer_cards) == 2:
        print("The dealer has",dealer_cards)
while len(player_cards) != 2:
    player_cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
    if len(player_cards) == 2:
        print("The player has",player_cards)

player_sum = sum(player_cards)
dealer_sum = sum(dealer_cards)

def dealercards():
    global dealer_sum, player_sum
    if dealer_sum >= 17:
        if dealer_sum > player_sum and dealer_sum <22:
            print("You lost!")
        elif dealer_sum == player_sum:
            print("It is a tie!")
        else:
            print("You won!")
    else:
        dealer_cards.append(random.randint(1,11)
        dealer_sum = sum(dealer_cards)
        dealercards()

def hitstay():
    status = input("Would you like to hit or stay?(h/s):")
    if status == h:
        player_cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
        print("You have ",player_cards)
        player_sum = sum(player_cards)
        if player_sum >= 21:
            print("You busted!")
            break
        else:
            hitstay()
    elif status == s:
        dealercards()
        
        
        

if player_sum = 21:
    print("You got a blackjack!")
elif dealer_sum = 21:
    print("The dealer got a blackjack, you lose!")
else:
    hitstay()
```

How do I make the code work? Thank you very much!

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Please provide an [mre]

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to add in the original code.